# Нужно проверять, что ссылка ведет на нужную страницу

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

И снова Доброго коллеги. Вот кусок кода: читает из файла url  и переходит по нему и дальше. Как добавить возможность проверки, что страница верная?

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

f = open(r"404.txt", 'w', encoding='utf8')

for url in line:
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except WebDriverException:
        print("Incorrect URL: {}".format(url))
        write_to_file(r"404.txt", "Incorrect URL: " + url)
    if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath):
        print('404: {}'.format(url))
        write_to_file(r"404.txt", "Ошибка 404: " + url)
        continue

driver.quit()
```

Comment: selenium ведь не может вернуть статус http, поэтому вы проверяли содержимое страницы `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath)`? А в чем вопрос?

Comment: А как определяется, верная ли страница?